# Documented examples from Microsoft don't work in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, graph-databases

Microsoft documented SQL Graph queries using `SHORTEST_PATH` do not work due to unexpected syntax errors

1. Create the sample database per the sample script shown here: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-sample?view=sqlallproducts-allversions)
2. Now try out to exercise SHORTEST_PATH by running the sample queries shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-shortest-path?view=sqlallproducts-allversions

All the documented queries fail due to syntactic errors around GRAPH PATH. For example, the following query fails:

```
SELECT
    Person1.name AS PersonName, 
    STRING_AGG(Person2.name, '->') WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS Friends
FROM
    Person AS Person1,
    friendOf FOR PATH AS fo,
Person FOR PATH  AS Person2
WHERE MATCH(SHORTEST_PATH(Person1(-(fo)->Person2)+))
AND Person1.name = 'Jacob'
```

Executing this query returns the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 108
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GRAPH'.

I suspect the documentation is somehow incorrect. What should the query be?

Comment: You mention an error multiple times, but you haven't actually supplied one in your question.

Comment: Thanks. Edited to show the error

Comment: Which database version are you running (`SELECT @@VERSION`)? Are you really on the SQL Server 2017 **compatibility level** (`SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id = DB_ID()` - should be **140** for SQL Server **2017**) ?

Comment: Database version:Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 00:26:19   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor) / Compatibility level: 140

Comment: Replication of error: [db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=164fab4f2b45c06d7344a0a0e0da5995)

Comment: Larnu, thanks for reproducing and introducing me to db Fiddle

Comment: This stuff is [new in SQL Server 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-ver15?view=sqlallproducts-allversions#graph). It's not going to work in SQL Server 2017. Admittedly the documentation is rubbish at indicating this -- you only get an oblique message if you [explicitly change the version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-shortest-path?view=sql-server-2017). If you change the version in db<>fiddle to 2019 CTP (Linux) the query runs successfully.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, indeed this works in SQL Server 2019!